# JHipster actual date

Tags: date, time, jhipster

Is there a way to get a field that return actual date/hour when I create an entity ? Cause post-editing my entities always gives me errors.

I've searched about it, and didn't seen anything. I tried with DateTime etc, but I would like that my field auto-fill with the date when the entry in the DB is made.e

Answer (score 3):

When saving your entity newly created, you can add a `LocalDate.now()` or `LocalDateTime.now()` to the field you want. Then you should hide the field Date in your form.
It worked for me. 
If you still want your field to show a date/time picker, it is already done : the date/time picker should select the actual date.

hope this helps

Comment: When saving ? I use yo jhipster:entity myEntity to create it, but they never propose me to add a localDate.now() :/

To be exact, I'm making a lil application where everyone from the dev teams can add info/links/etc, and I would like to register in database the date and time when they add their info/links/etc ;)

Comment: You can surely get a field which will store a Date. The correct type is LocalDate.

Then, when calling the method .save() of your entity service, you can set its date with setDate(LocalDate.now())

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in code as Rousseau Alban explained or if you only want current date, you can let the database do it for you on insert: just add a default value to your column in the Liquibase changelog created by JHipster for your table's entity, it should be anmed something like `2016***_added_entity_***.xml`. You can see an example in `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` in `jhi_user table` for field `created_date`.

```
    <column name="created_date" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
```

Drop your database and restart your app to re-create it.

Comment: <column name="posted_at" type="timestamp" defaultValueDate="${now}">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>



I changed the posted_at, but when I rebuild with mvn, I got an error, the website works but nothing new on the "Liens" entity page.

Comment: Of course because teh valuie is generated by the database on saving, it has nothing to do with UI

Comment: 1 - I made my entity with yo jhipster:entity myEntity
Then I downed the serveur, going to files you said earlier, and changed the values for the one I said "type="timestamp and defaultValueDate" but still doesn't works. This time, I got no error, but I see any difference :/